# Magento 2 get all level of parent

Tags: magento2, category

I am getting Current category Parent category and all Subcategory it working fine

```
<?php 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
    $base_url = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
    $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
    $category_name =  $category->getName();    
     if($this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory()):
    $subcategories=$this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory()->getCategories($this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory()->getId());?>
            <a class="active" href="<?php echo $category->getParentCategory()->getUrl();?>"><?php echo $category->getParentCategory()->getName();?><i class="icon-right-arrow"></i></a>
        <a class="active" href=""><?php echo $category_name;?><i class="icon-right-arrow"></i></a>
      </li>
       <?php 
        $i = 0;
        foreach($subcategories as $subcategory){?>
                <li>
                  <a href="<?php echo $base_url.$subcategory->getrequest_path();?>" title="<?php echo $subcategory->getName();?>">
                  <?php echo $subcategory->getName();?></a>
                </li>

        <?php   $i++;
                if($i==8){
                    break;
                  }  
        }?>

        </ul>
            </div>

    <?php //}
    endif;
?>
```

But i want all level of parent How to get it

Comment: You need complete category tree ?

Comment: Not complete current category all parent & Subcategory

Comment: okay tree from current category till n depth

Comment: Yes Correct .....